# Why would a parallel version of accumulate be so much slower?

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency

Inspired by [Antony Williams' "C++ Concurrency in Action"](https://www.manning.com/books/c-plus-plus-concurrency-in-action) I took a closer look at his parallel version of `std::accumulate`. I copied its code from the book and added some output for debugging purposes and this is what I ended up with:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

template <typename Iterator, typename T>
struct accumulate_block
{
  T operator()(Iterator first, Iterator last)
  {
    return std::accumulate(first, last, T());
  }
};

template <typename Iterator, typename T>
T parallel_accumulate(Iterator first, Iterator last, T init)
{
  const unsigned long length = std::distance(first, last);

  if (!length) return init;

  const unsigned long min_per_thread = 25;
  const unsigned long max_threads    = (length) / min_per_thread;
  const unsigned long hardware_conc  = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
  const unsigned long num_threads    = std::min(hardware_conc != 0 ? hardware_conc : 2, max_threads);
  const unsigned long block_size     = length / num_threads;

  std::vector<std::future<T>> futures(num_threads - 1);
  std::vector<std::thread> threads(num_threads - 1);

  Iterator block_start = first;
  for (unsigned long i = 0; i < (num_threads - 1); ++i)
  {
    Iterator block_end = block_start;
    std::advance(block_end, block_size);

    std::packaged_task<T(Iterator, Iterator)> task{accumulate_block<Iterator, T>()};
    futures[i] = task.get_future();
    threads[i] = std::thread(std::move(task), block_start, block_end);
    block_start = block_end;
  }

  T last_result = accumulate_block<Iterator, T>()(block_start, last);

  for (auto& t : threads) t.join();

  T result = init;
  for (unsigned long i = 0; i < (num_threads - 1); ++i) {
    result += futures[i].get();
  }
  result += last_result;
  return result;
}

template <typename TimeT = std::chrono::microseconds>
struct measure
{
  template <typename F, typename... Args>
  static typename TimeT::rep execution(F func, Args&&... args)
  {
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto start = system_clock::now();
    func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    auto duration = duration_cast<TimeT>(system_clock::now() - start);
    return duration.count();
  }
};

template <typename T>
T parallel(const std::vector<T>& v)
{
  return parallel_accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
}

template <typename T>
T stdaccumulate(const std::vector<T>& v)
{
  return std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
}

int main()
{
  constexpr unsigned int COUNT = 200000000;
  std::vector<int> v(COUNT);

  // optional randomising vector contents - std::accumulate also gives 0us
  // but custom parallel accumulate gives longer times with randomised input
  std::mt19937 mersenne_engine;
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(1, 100);
  auto gen = std::bind(dist, mersenne_engine);
  std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), gen);
  std::fill(v.begin(), v.end(), 1);

  auto v2 = v; // copy to work on the same data

  std::cout << "starting ... " << '\n';
  std::cout << "std::accumulate : \t" << measure<>::execution(stdaccumulate<int>, v) << "us" << '\n';
  std::cout << "parallel: \t" << measure<>::execution(parallel<int>, v2) << "us" << '\n';
}
```

What is most interesting here is that almost always I will get 0 length time from `std::accumulate`.

Exemplar output:

```
starting ... 
std::accumulate :       0us
parallel: 
inside1 54us

inside2 81830us

inside3 89082us
89770us
```

What is the problem here?

http://cpp.sh/6jbt

Comment: At first glance, this appears to read much like "debug my code plz" question - what are you actually asking here?

Comment: I am wondering why is that version presented in Anthony's book so much slower? Is that a problem wit input data or code is too busy managing concurrency than to work actual accumulating?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth What he is asking is written in the title of the question.

Comment: Well, for a start, there's no way that 200e6 iterations can take <1us - so something is up with your profiling ;)

Comment: Zero time for sequential `std::accumulate` is weird. I wonder if a compiler might have optimized it out completely since you don't use the result anywhere. Could you print out the result, just to be sure?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As is the usual case with micro-benchmarking, you need to make sure that your code is actually *doing something*. You're doing an `accumulate`, but you're not actually storing the result anywhere or doing anything with it. So do you really need to have done any of the work anyway? The compiler just snipped out all that logic in the normal case. That's why you get `0`.

Just change your code to actually ensure that work needs to be done. For example:

```
int s, s2;
std::cout << "starting ... " << '\n';
std::cout << "std::accumulate : \t"
          << measure<>::execution([&]{s = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);})
          << "us\n";
std::cout << "parallel: \t"
          << measure<>::execution([&]{s2 = parallel_accumulate(v2.begin(), v2.end(), 0);})
          << "us\n";
std::cout << s << ',' << s2 << std::endl;
```

Comment: You're exactly right @Barry! I have changed my code as well and it appeared that it's pretty close with little advantage to the parallel version. (or next time I won't check this type of benchmarks with `-O3` :) )

Comment: @Patryk -- The biggest problem with your code is that it's monolithic. My experience is that proper benchmarking requires multiple compilation units. The standard library is chock full of functions that call functions that call functions that call functions ...BUT proper optimization collapses those to a small number of assembly instructions with no function calls whatsoever. Failing to compile the test article with proper optimization means one is not taking full advantage of C++. ...

Comment: On the other hand, the compiler may well see that it doesn't have to do anything at all if one compiles everything monolithically at a high level of optimization. The test driver needs to be compiled at a low level of optimization, while the test article needs to be compiled optimized.